# Jacobian of transformation swapping elements

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, vector-analysis, jacobian

Suppose I have the following transformation
$$
\phi(x, y) = (y, x)
$$
that swaps the order of $x$ and $y$. I am told that its jacobian determinant is $1$, i..e $|\text{det}\phi'(x)|=1$. How can I show this?

Comment: Do you know the definition of the Jacobian? It will be easier if we write X = y, Y = x, using capital letters to distinguish the transformation.

Comment: ooh so maybe something like 
$$
\Bigg\lvert \text{det}\left[\begin{pmatrix}
    \partial_x y & \partial_y y \\
    \partial_x x & \partial_y x
\end{pmatrix}\right]\Bigg\rvert =\Bigg\lvert \text{det}\left[ \begin{pmatrix}
    0 & 1 \\
   1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}\right]\Bigg\rvert = |-1| = 1
$$

Answer (score 0):

The function is linear from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to itself. The gradient (at any point) of a linear function is the function itself. Thus, the Jacobian is just the (absolute value of the) determinant of the matrix that represents the function,

i.e., $|\det(\nabla\phi)|=\Bigl|\det\Bigl(\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\1&0\\ \end{pmatrix}\Bigl)\Bigl|=|-1|=1$.

For general functions, one must look at the definition of the gradient of a function from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to itself and compute it. Then, take the absolute value of the determinant.
One can check that for linear functions, this definition gives back the matrix that represent the function itself.

Note again that linear functions have the same gradient (hence the same Jacobian) everywhere (for every $(x,y)$), but this in general depends on the point we are considering.

Comment: I didn't even think this was a linear function to be honest

Comment: Well, with this I mean that $\phi(x,y)=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\1&0\\ \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\ \end{pmatrix}$. It is represented by a multiplication by a given matrix. Then, the matrix is also the gradient at any point basically.

Comment: This is brilliant, thank you!